# sudo apt-get update is not working in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-20.04

sudo apt update is not working in ubuntu.
I get this errors E: Type 'gpg' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
E: The list of sources could not be read. when I run sudo apt update command.

I want solution for E: Type 'gpg' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
E: The list of sources could not be read for this error.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this command to fix your problem --

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
```